# How to retrain a fitted saved model in neural prophet with new additional datapoints?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, facebook-prophet

I know how to do this in fbProphet - you get the parameters from the old model and update them using the new data points, instead of retraining the whole model from scratch. How to do the same with Neural Prophet? I tried the same function but it didn't work out. I read the documentation but nothing is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reached out to the developers of the tool on GitHub and they said that this feature was disabled. Here is the link: https://github.com/ourownstory/neural_prophet/discussions/729

In case you feel that this feature is important, please join the discussion.